# Can Ramanujan–Sato like series generate rational numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[Ramanujan–Sato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series) like series in the title refers to the shape of

$$
C=\sum_{k=0}^{∞}s(n)⋅t^{k}×{\frac{P(k)}{Q(k)}}.
$$

The common $s(n)$ is generally in the form of factorial divided by factorial, $t$ is any non-zero rational number, $P(k), Q(k)$ are integer coefficient polynomials.

---

I found that many famous irrational constants can be expressed in similar forms:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{π}&=\sum_{n=0}^∞\left(\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^3\frac{(6n+1)}{2^{8n+2}}\\
\frac{1}{π}&=\sum_{n=0}^∞\left(\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^3\frac{(42n+5)}{2^{12n+4}}\\
C_{\mathrm{atalan}}&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^∞\left(\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\right)^3\frac{3n+2}{(2n+1)^3}×(-8)^{n}\\
C_{\mathrm{atalan}}&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^∞\left(\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\right)^3\frac{4n+3}{(2n+1)^3}×(-64)^{n}\\
ζ(3)&=\frac{2}{7}\sum_{n=0}^∞\left(\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\right)^5\frac{10n^2+14n+5}{(2n+1)^5}×(-256)^{n}\\
\frac{1}{π^3}&=\sum_{n=0}^∞\left(\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^7\frac{168n^3+76n^2+14n+1}{2^{20n+5}}\\
π^4&=\sum_{n=0}^∞\left(\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\right)^7\frac{21n^3+41n^2+27n+6}{(2n+1)^7}×2^{8n+4}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

> *In order to simplify the programmatic search, $s(n)=\left(\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^{2p+1}$ is selected here.*
> *The actual Ramanujan–Sato $s(n)$ in series can have many other forms.*

I want to know whether this form of series can express non-zero integers or rational numbers?

$$
\frac{p}{q}=\sum_{k=0}^{∞}s(n)⋅t^{k}×{\frac{P(k)}{Q(k)}}
$$

Comment: It seems some trivial examples are when $P$ is the zero polynomial. Also when $s(n)\equiv 1$ and $P=Q$ then $2=\sum_{k=0}^1 \left(\frac 12\right)^k \frac{P(k)}{Q(k)}$.

Comment: The answer to this question could only have been "yes" or "we don't know", since it's unknown whether Catalan's constant is rational.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, then I think the answer is yes.

We have
$$2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\cdot\bigg(\frac 14\bigg)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n+1}\tag1$$
$$\frac 43=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\cdot\bigg(\frac 14\bigg)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n+2}\tag2$$
$$\frac{16}{15}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\cdot\bigg(\frac 14\bigg)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n+3}\tag3$$
$$\frac{32}{35}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\cdot\bigg(\frac 14\bigg)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n+4}\tag4$$

*Proof* :

Using the binomial theorem, we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=(1-x)^{-1/2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}(-1)^n x^n =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}x^n$$
Multiplying by $x^a$, we have
$$\frac{x^a}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}x^{n+a}$$
So, we have
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^a}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}x^{n+a}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}\cdot\frac{1}{n+a+1}$$

For $a=0,1,2$ and $3$, we get $(1),(2),(3)$ and $(4)$.$\ \square$